# Leaflet.streetlabels with leaflet-side-by-side not working

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-plugins

I was trying to mix some Leaflet Plugins, namely

leaflet-side-by-side (https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-side-by-side),
Leaflet.streetlabels ( https://github.com/triedeti/Leaflet.streetlabels ),

the latter based on Leaflet.LabelTextCollision (https://github.com/yakitoritabetai/Leaflet.LabelTextCollision)

My first issue was that I am using L.ImageOverlay and not a tile layer, so I needed to modify the leaflet-side-by-side code a bit as by this issue: https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-side-by-side/issues/4

Then everything worked except the streetnames are not appearing in their associated panes but in the background.
Here is a fiddle illustrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/FiddleHeimer3000/Ldqsohb1/57/

I guess this has to do with the text getting rendered directly to canvas?
Maybe someone has another idea how I could get this to work?
Maybe there is another way to render the streetnames on top of the ImageOverlay?

Edit: The example code:

```
    (function(){function r(e,n,t){function o(i,f){if(!n[i]){if(!e[i]){var c="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!f&&c)return c(i,!0);if(u)return u(i,!0);var a=new Error("Cannot find module '"+i+"'");throw a.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",a}var p=n[i]={exports:{}};e[i][0].call(p.exports,function(r){var n=e[i][1][r];return o(n||r)},p,p.exports,r,e,n,t)}return n[i].exports}for(var u="function"==typeof require&&require,i=0;i<t.length;i++)o(t[i]);return o}return r})()({1:[function(require,module,exports){
(function (global){
var L = (typeof window !== "undefined" ? window['L'] : typeof global !== "undefined" ? global['L'] : null)
require('./layout.css')
require('./range.css')

var mapWasDragEnabled
var mapWasTapEnabled

// Leaflet v0.7 backwards compatibility
function on (el, types, fn, context) {
  types.split(' ').forEach(function (type) {
    L.DomEvent.on(el, type, fn, context)
  })
}

// Leaflet v0.7 backwards compatibility
function off (el, types, fn, context) {
  types.split(' ').forEach(function (type) {
    L.DomEvent.off(el, type, fn, context)
  })
}

function getRangeEvent (rangeInput) {
  return 'oninput' in rangeInput ? 'input' : 'change'
}

function cancelMapDrag () {
  mapWasDragEnabled = this._map.dragging.enabled()
  mapWasTapEnabled = this._map.tap && this._map.tap.enabled()
  this._map.dragging.disable()
  this._map.tap && this._map.tap.disable()
}

function uncancelMapDrag (e) {
  this._refocusOnMap(e)
  if (mapWasDragEnabled) {
    this._map.dragging.enable()
  }
  if (mapWasTapEnabled) {
    this._map.tap.enable()
  }
}

// convert arg to an array - returns empty array if arg is undefined
function asArray (arg) {
  return (arg === 'undefined') ? [] : Array.isArray(arg) ? arg : [arg]
}

function noop () {}

L.Control.SideBySide = L.Control.extend({
  options: {
    thumbSize: 42,
    padding: 0
  },

  initialize: function (leftLayers, rightLayers, options) {
    this.setLeftLayers(leftLayers)
    this.setRightLayers(rightLayers)
    L.setOptions(this, options)
  },

  getPosition: function () {
    var rangeValue = this._range.value
    var offset = (0.5 - rangeValue) * (2 * this.options.padding + this.options.thumbSize)
    return this._map.getSize().x * rangeValue + offset
  },

  setPosition: noop,

  includes: L.Evented.prototype || L.Mixin.Events,

  addTo: function (map) {
    this.remove()
    this._map = map

    var container = this._container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-sbs', map._controlContainer)

    this._divider = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-sbs-divider', container)
    var range = this._range = L.DomUtil.create('input', 'leaflet-sbs-range', container)
    range.type = 'range'
    range.min = 0
    range.max = 1
    range.step = 'any'
    range.value = 0.5
    range.style.paddingLeft = range.style.paddingRight = this.options.padding + 'px'
    this._addEvents()
    this._updateLayers()
    return this
  },

  remove: function () {
    if (!this._map) {
      return this
    }
    if (this._leftLayer) {
      this._leftLayer.getPane().style.clip = ''
    }
    if (this._rightLayer) {
      this._rightLayer.getPane().style.clip = ''
    }
    this._removeEvents()
    L.DomUtil.remove(this._container)

    this._map = null

    return this
  },

  setLeftLayers: function (leftLayers) {
    this._leftLayers = asArray(leftLayers)
    this._updateLayers()
    return this
  },

  setRightLayers: function (rightLayers) {
    this._rightLayers = asArray(rightLayers)
    this._updateLayers()
    return this
  },

  _updateClip: function () {
    var map = this._map
    var nw = map.containerPointToLayerPoint([0, 0])
    var se = map.containerPointToLayerPoint(map.getSize())
    var clipX = nw.x + this.getPosition()
    var dividerX = this.getPosition()

    this._divider.style.left = dividerX + 'px'
    this.fire('dividermove', {x: dividerX})
    var clipLeft = 'rect(' + [nw.y, clipX, se.y, nw.x].join('px,') + 'px)'
    var clipRight = 'rect(' + [nw.y, se.x, se.y, clipX].join('px,') + 'px)'
    if (this._leftLayer) {
      this._leftLayer.getPane().style.clip = clipLeft
    }
    if (this._rightLayer) {
      this._rightLayer.getPane().style.clip = clipRight
    }
  },

  _updateLayers: function () {
    if (!this._map) {
      return this
    }
    var prevLeft = this._leftLayer
    var prevRight = this._rightLayer
    this._leftLayer = this._rightLayer = null
    this._leftLayers.forEach(function (layer) {
      if (this._map.hasLayer(layer)) {
        this._leftLayer = layer
      }
    }, this)
    this._rightLayers.forEach(function (layer) {
      if (this._map.hasLayer(layer)) {
        this._rightLayer = layer
      }
    }, this)
    if (prevLeft !== this._leftLayer) {
      prevLeft && this.fire('leftlayerremove', {layer: prevLeft})
      this._leftLayer && this.fire('leftlayeradd', {layer: this._leftLayer})
    }
    if (prevRight !== this._rightLayer) {
      prevRight && this.fire('rightlayerremove', {layer: prevRight})
      this._rightLayer && this.fire('rightlayeradd', {layer: this._rightLayer})
    }
    this._updateClip()
  },

  _addEvents: function () {
    var range = this._range
    var map = this._map
    if (!map || !range) return
    map.on('move', this._updateClip, this)
    map.on('layeradd layerremove', this._updateLayers, this)
    on(range, getRangeEvent(range), this._updateClip, this)
    on(range, L.Browser.touch ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown', cancelMapDrag, this)
    on(range, L.Browser.touch ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup', uncancelMapDrag, this)
  },

  _removeEvents: function () {
    var range = this._range
    var map = this._map
    if (range) {
      off(range, getRangeEvent(range), this._updateClip, this)
      off(range, L.Browser.touch ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown', cancelMapDrag, this)
      off(range, L.Browser.touch ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup', uncancelMapDrag, this)
    }
    if (map) {
      map.off('layeradd layerremove', this._updateLayers, this)
      map.off('move', this._updateClip, this)
    }
  }
})

L.control.sideBySide = function (leftLayers, rightLayers, options) {
  return new L.Control.SideBySide(leftLayers, rightLayers, options)
}

module.exports = L.Control.SideBySide

}).call(this,typeof global !== "undefined" ? global : typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : {})
},{"./layout.css":2,"./range.css":4}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
var inject = require('./node_modules/cssify');
var css = ".leaflet-sbs-range {\r\n    position: absolute;\r\n    top: 50%;\r\n    width: 100%;\r\n    z-index: 999;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-divider {\r\n    position: absolute;\r\n    top: 0;\r\n    bottom: 0;\r\n    left: 50%;\r\n    margin-left: -2px;\r\n    width: 4px;\r\n    background-color: #fff;\r\n    pointer-events: none;\r\n    z-index: 999;\r\n}\r\n";
inject(css, undefined, '_i6aomd');
module.exports = css;

},{"./node_modules/cssify":3}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict'

function injectStyleTag (document, fileName, cb) {
  var style = document.getElementById(fileName)

  if (style) {
    cb(style)
  } else {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]

    style = document.createElement('style')
    if (fileName != null) style.id = fileName
    cb(style)
    head.appendChild(style)
  }

  return style
}

module.exports = function (css, customDocument, fileName) {
  var doc = customDocument || document
  /* istanbul ignore if: not supported by Electron */
  if (doc.createStyleSheet) {
    var sheet = doc.createStyleSheet()
    sheet.cssText = css
    return sheet.ownerNode
  } else {
    return injectStyleTag(doc, fileName, function (style) {
      /* istanbul ignore if: not supported by Electron */
      if (style.styleSheet) {
        style.styleSheet.cssText = css
      } else {
        style.innerHTML = css
      }
    })
  }
}

module.exports.byUrl = function (url) {
  /* istanbul ignore if: not supported by Electron */
  if (document.createStyleSheet) {
    return document.createStyleSheet(url).ownerNode
  } else {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
    var link = document.createElement('link')

    link.rel = 'stylesheet'
    link.href = url

    head.appendChild(link)
    return link
  }
}

},{}],4:[function(require,module,exports){
var inject = require('./node_modules/cssify');
var css = ".leaflet-sbs-range {\r\n    -webkit-appearance: none;\r\n    display: inline-block!important;\r\n    vertical-align: middle;\r\n    height: 0;\r\n    padding: 0;\r\n    margin: 0;\r\n    border: 0;\r\n    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);\r\n    min-width: 100px;\r\n    cursor: pointer;\r\n    pointer-events: none;\r\n    z-index: 999;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-ms-fill-upper {\r\n    background: transparent;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-ms-fill-lower {\r\n    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);\r\n}\r\n/* Browser thingies */\r\n\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-moz-range-track {\r\n    opacity: 0;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-ms-track {\r\n    opacity: 0;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-ms-tooltip {\r\n    display: none;\r\n}\r\n/* For whatever reason, these need to be defined\r\n * on their own so dont group them */\r\n\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {\r\n    -webkit-appearance: none;\r\n    margin: 0;\r\n    padding: 0;\r\n    background: #fff;\r\n    height: 40px;\r\n    width: 40px;\r\n    border-radius: 20px;\r\n    cursor: ew-resize;\r\n    pointer-events: auto;\r\n    border: 1px solid #ddd;\r\n    background-image: url(\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABQCAMAAAC5zwKfAAAABlBMVEV9fX3///+Kct39AAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAA9SURBVFjD7dehDQAwDANBZ/+l2wmKoiqR7pHRcaeaCxAIBAL/g7k9JxAIBAKBQCAQCAQC14H+MhAIBE4CD3fOFvGVBzhZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\");\r\n    background-position: 50% 50%;\r\n    background-repeat: no-repeat;\r\n    background-size: 40px 40px;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-ms-thumb {\r\n    margin: 0;\r\n    padding: 0;\r\n    background: #fff;\r\n    height: 40px;\r\n    width: 40px;\r\n    border-radius: 20px;\r\n    cursor: ew-resize;\r\n    pointer-events: auto;\r\n    border: 1px solid #ddd;\r\n    background-image: url(\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABQCAMAAAC5zwKfAAAABlBMVEV9fX3///+Kct39AAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAA9SURBVFjD7dehDQAwDANBZ/+l2wmKoiqR7pHRcaeaCxAIBAL/g7k9JxAIBAKBQCAQCAQC14H+MhAIBE4CD3fOFvGVBzhZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\");\r\n    background-position: 50% 50%;\r\n    background-repeat: no-repeat;\r\n    background-size: 40px 40px;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-moz-range-thumb {\r\n    padding: 0;\r\n    right: 0    ;\r\n    background: #fff;\r\n    height: 40px;\r\n    width: 40px;\r\n    border-radius: 20px;\r\n    cursor: ew-resize;\r\n    pointer-events: auto;\r\n    border: 1px solid #ddd;\r\n    background-image: url(\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABQCAMAAAC5zwKfAAAABlBMVEV9fX3///+Kct39AAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAA9SURBVFjD7dehDQAwDANBZ/+l2wmKoiqR7pHRcaeaCxAIBAL/g7k9JxAIBAKBQCAQCAQC14H+MhAIBE4CD3fOFvGVBzhZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\");\r\n    background-position: 50% 50%;\r\n    background-repeat: no-repeat;\r\n    background-size: 40px 40px;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range:disabled::-moz-range-thumb {\r\n    cursor: default;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range:disabled::-ms-thumb {\r\n    cursor: default;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range:disabled::-webkit-slider-thumb {\r\n    cursor: default;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range:disabled {\r\n    cursor: default;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range:focus {\r\n    outline: none!important;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-moz-focus-outer {\r\n    border: 0;\r\n}\r\n\r\n";
inject(css, undefined, '_1tlt668');
module.exports = css;

},{"./node_modules/cssify":3}]},{},[1]);

//end modified Leaflet-side-by-side
var streets0 = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "street0", "type": "pedestrian" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates":  [ [ 867, 764  ], [  4075,2688 ] ] } }
]
};
var streets1 = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "street1", "type": "pedestrian" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates":  [  [ 373, 1150  ],[ 1499, 138  ] ] } }
]
};

var scalefac=1.5;
var map_w = 1200;
var map_h = 1080;
var w = map_w * scalefac;
var h = map_h * scalefac;

var ww =  document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var hh =  document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var minzoom= -3;
var maxzoom=-1;
var curr_zoom;
var bounds = [[0,0], [h,w]];
var map
var map_image_overlays = {
    
};;
var center;
var left_pane;
var left_layer
var right_pane;
var right_layer;
var left_polylayer
var right_polylayer

var streetLabelsRenderer = new L.StreetLabels({
      
      collisionFlg: true,
      propertyName: 'name',
      showLabelIf: function (layer) {
        return true; 
      },
     
      fontStyle: {
        dynamicFontSize: false,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontSizeUnit: "px",
        lineWidth: 40,
        fillStyle: "black",
        strokeStyle: "white",
      },
    });

center = new L.LatLng( 1752,2136 );

map = L.map('map', {
            renderer: streetLabelsRenderer,
            crs: L.CRS.Simple,
            dragging:true,
            touchZoom:true,
            zoomSnap:0.01,
            //zoomDelta:0.2,
            minZoom: minzoom,
            maxZoom: maxzoom,
            keepBuffer: 10,
            updateWhenZooming: true,
            zoomAnimation:false,
            attributionControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            zoomsliderControl: true,
            
        });
map.fitBounds(bounds);
L.control.zoom({position:"bottomleft"}).addTo(map)
map.fitBounds(bounds);
        
var left_pane=map.createPane('left');
var right_pane=map.createPane('right');
map_image_overlays.map0 = L.imageOverlay('https://placekitten.com/1200/1080', bounds,{ pane: "left",opacity:0.7});
map_image_overlays.map1 = L.imageOverlay('https://placekitten.com/g/1200/1080', bounds,{ pane:"right",opacity:0.7});
left_layer = map_image_overlays.map0.addTo(map);
right_layer = map_image_overlays.map1.addTo(map);

var leftStreetsDataset = L.geoJSON(streets0 );
var rightStreetsDataset = L.geoJSON(streets1);
left_streetslayer=leftStreetsDataset.addTo(map);
right_streetslayer=rightStreetsDataset.addTo(map);

var geo0 = [{
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [[ 373, 1150 ], [ 473, 1150 ], [ 573, 1150 ]]
}, {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [[499, 400], [499, 430], [499, 430]]
}];
var geo1 = [{
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [[ 673, 1150 ], [ 773, 1150 ], [ 873, 1150 ]]
}, {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [[699, 600], [699, 830], [699, 1430]]
}];

var geo0_layer=L.geoJSON(geo0,{style: {"color": "red","weight": 50},pane:"left"}).addTo(map);
var geo1_layer=L.geoJSON(geo1,{style: {"color": "green","weight": 50},pane:"right"}).addTo(map);

L.control.sideBySide([left_layer],[right_layer,geo1_layer]).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Coding questions on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise  they will must likely be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: There is a link to a jsfiddle including all the code. Not enough?

Comment: Answers to questions on GIS SE site are equally intended for person asking as for others with similar question/problems. Outside links tend to get lost in time and if relevant code is not part of the question, it can be later hard to guess what the question was all about. Link to JSFiddle is of course a bonus to the person answering, since he/she can quickly asses where the problem ot solution is.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are out of luck here. Since you are using Leaflet plugins `leaflet-side-by-side` and `Leaflet.streetlabels`, and the latter uses another two Leaflet plugins `Leaflet.LabelTextCollison` and `Canvas-TextPath`, it's impossible to control final behaviour on the map.

In your code, you missed declaring target panes for street GeoJSON layers. It should be:

```
var leftStreetsDataset = L.geoJSON(streets0, {
  pane:"left",
});
var rightStreetsDataset = L.geoJSON(streets1, {
  pane:"right",
});
```

In this case, streets are displayed correctly in corresponding panes, but without labels (blue lines):

[image]

This means that renderer `streetLabelsRenderer` was not used for those layers. But if renderer is explicitly specified when defining layers:

```
var leftStreetsDataset = L.geoJSON(streets0, {
  pane:"left",
  renderer: streetLabelsRenderer
});
var rightStreetsDataset = L.geoJSON(streets1, {
  pane:"right",
  renderer: streetLabelsRenderer
});
```

then map panes are ignored and streets with labels appear on both sides:

[image]

To solve this would require quite some work, to go through code of all four plugins and modify one or several of them.

Comment: Hello. 
Thanks for the answer. 
I am sorry I should have mentioned that I went through the options you described. 
Looking through the plugins I realized that the streetnames are rendered on Canvas which is displayed under all other layers.
The panes however do no have their own canvas layers. 
I would have to re-write the side-by-side plugin to use canvas for the panes. 
That would be overkill for my purpose so I go with ye olde L.DivIcon for the streetnames.